# Separate SQLite transactions in multiple threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, sqlite

My application's update process grabs data from three separate sources (e.g.,Twitter, Facebook, and Google). We update each at the same time in a separate thread for performance reasons and would like each one to have their own SQLite transaction since we may be processing ~500 items at once which can take several seconds.

Is there a way to begin a new transaction in a thread which does not "interfere" with other threads interaction of the database?

TLDR: Can you have multiple SQLite transactions across different threads?

---

**Update**: E.g., consider the following code:

```
@implementation Update

- (void)prepareUpdate {
    [self update:@"Twitter"];
    [self update:@"Facebook"];
    [self update:@"Google"];
}

- (void)update:(NSString *)platform {
    dispatch_queue_t newThread = dispatch_queue_create("newThread", NULL);
    dispatch_async(newThread, ^{

        NSDictionary * data = [Platform getData:platform];

        [_db beginTransaction];
            for (id item in data) {
                [Platform update:platform withData:item];
            }
        [_db endTransaction];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"Update complete!");

        });
    });
}

@end
```

Which will generate the following error:

```
Error whilst preparing query: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

Comment: probably i would use a `@syncrhonized` function to access the database and send all the transactions through the same object

Comment: I don't want a centralised point of query'ing as the user should still be able to use the app/database whilst the updates are being performed in the background.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has one transaction per connection, so to get multiple transactions, you need multiple connections (i.e., database objects).

However, it is not possible for [multiple transactions to write to the database at the same time](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll need to open a few more connections, then.

Comment: Hmm. I have tried creating two connections to the same database (`sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db1);` and `sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db2);`), but when I try and query with them I get a multitude or errors such as `no such table: xyz`, `database is locked`, and `unknown error`. Basically it seems as though opening two connections to the sane table is not liked very much.

P.s. Looking at their pointers they do point to two different memory locations.

Comment: Then there are some bugs in your app.

Answer (score 0):

**As the simple question has been asked**
Replay is Yes you can have multiple SQLite transaction across different threads.
[Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)
[image]

---

**More reference**
`Is SQLite threadsafe?`
SQLite is threadsafe. We make this concession since many users choose to ignore the advice given in the previous paragraph. But in order to be thread-safe, SQLite must be compiled with the SQLITE_THREADSAFE preprocessor macro set to 1. Both the Windows and Linux precompiled binaries in the distribution are compiled this way. If you are unsure if the SQLite library you are linking against is compiled to be threadsafe you can call the sqlite3_threadsafe() interface to find out.

SQLite is threadsafe because it uses mutexes to serialize access to common data structures. However, the work of acquiring and releasing these mutexes will slow SQLite down slightly. Hence, if you do not need SQLite to be threadsafe, you should disable the mutexes for maximum performance. See the threading mode documentation for additional information.

Under Unix, you should not carry an open SQLite database across a fork() system call into the child process.
[image]

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)

Comment: Hi there @Jageen, I'm already calling `sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);` when I create the database connection, and have updated my initial post with a snippet of how I am opening a new thread, running a new transaction, which leads to the erorr `Error whilst preparing query: cannot start a transaction within a transaction`.

Comment: I thought you just want that is it possible or not, let me check with new update :)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about multiple transactions.

Comment: @CL.OP has changed question first question was "Can you have multiple SQLite transactions across different threads?" now reexamine my answer and review it again thanks

Comment: The only [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27442559/revisions) was the addition of code.